Automatic Drawing of Cross section of a Canal using given data
I want to automate the process of drawing a cross section of a canal with the Given data Initial Level, proposed level , existing level to draw a graph with each give point noted in a Table Below
What program and in which language can i make to accomplish this
Eg.
Cross section of a canal
Thank You In advance for any input in this Topic :)
below given is the link to a drive folder that contains a excel files that can do similar work using macros and input data for a cross section.
also photos of a cross section made with the macros file using a given set of data in another folder.
Files
The macros work by updating the 3 columns data at the start clicking copy button which copy's command to the clipboard and then selecting polyline in autocad and pasting the copied command.

If You are looking for program, You can use for example Civil, or TcpMDT.
If You are looking for language where you can automate it by yourself, You may need base CAD application like AutoCAD, ZWCAD, BricsCAD or other and pogramming language like AutoLISP, C#, C++.
Also you can use just ezDXF, in this case You may not need CAD
but in this case, prepare for a lot of work before success.
Can You share input data You have ?

i already have a excel file that do that work using macros i can share that as it might be helpful and the input data

i have shared the files and data please feel free to ask any more questions required and thank you for your input in this personal project :)
